# How to update the quantity of all items in the cart with one update button

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-2, c#-4.0

I have the following action method, when I press the update button on my cart and post to this method I need it bind all productId and partquantity values into the respective parameters/arrays (int[] ProductId, int[] partquantity) and it does this. I am presuming when form data, that is keys and values are posted they arrive in some sort of order, likely as elements are laid out on the HTML page (top to bottom)? So I wish for the operation on each cart item to be performed using the correct partquantity entered, that is for the correct productId. I am guessing if they post and bind in strict order then partquantity[2] should be the correct quantity for ProductId[2] etc. ?

The below logic in trying to increment f by 1 for each operation on each productId in the ProductId[] array does not work.  I need to get this to work because say I have 5 items added to the cart and change the quantity for 4 of them I wish to just press the one update button and it will update for all these items\lines in the cart. So method needs to catch all the posted productId and quantities and use in the correct order, so the right quantity is assigned to the right cart item which is looked up by ProductId.

```
public RedirectToRouteResult UpdateCart(Cart cart, int[] ProductId, int[] partquantity, string returnUrl)
{
   int f = 0;
   int x = partquantity.Length;

   while (f <= x) 
   {
     foreach (var pid in ProductId)
     {
       f++;
       var cartItem = cart.Lines.FirstOrDefault(c => c.Product.ProductID == pid);
       cartItem.Quantity = partquantity[f];
     }
   }
   return RedirectToAction("Index", new { returnUrl });
 }
```

This is the View:

```
<% foreach (var line in Model.Cart.Lines)
 { %>
  <tr>
    <td align="center"><%: Html.TextBox("partquantity", line.Quantity)%></td>
    <td align="left"><%: line.Product.Name%></td>
    <td align="right"><%: line.Product.ListPrice.ToString("c")%></td>
    <td align="right">
    <%: (line.Quantity * line.Product.ListPrice).ToString("c")%>
    </td>
  </tr>
<%: Html.Hidden("ProductId", line.Product.ProductID)%>
<% } %>
```

Custom Binder

```
    public class CartModelBinder : IModelBinder
{

    private const string cartSessionKey = "_cart";

    public object BindModel(ControllerContext controllerContext, ModelBindingContext bindingContext)
    {

        if (bindingContext.Model != null)
            throw new InvalidOperationException("Cannot update instances");

        Cart cart = (Cart)controllerContext.HttpContext.Session[cartSessionKey];

        if (cart == null)
        {
            cart = new Cart();
            controllerContext.HttpContext.Session[cartSessionKey] = cart;

        }

        return cart;

    }
}
```

}

Comment: Please spend some time to format your question to make it easy to read.

Comment: What are you trying to do in your `UpdateCart` action? Your outer loop seems to be a loop from `0` to `partquantity.Length`, but you increment the counter inside the `foreach` loop for products. So if your `ProductId` array is larger than the `partquantity` array, you will at some point go out of bounds when trying to access `partquantity[f]`. If the idea is that the `ProductId` and `partquantity` arrays are equal lengths, why would you need two loops for this anyway?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your Cart object should be enough as parameter for this scenario, you can have something like this.

The general idea would be to use an index so you get your Cart object with your Lines as you passed them to the view originally but with updated Quantity values.

Your model as I understand it:

```
public class Cart
{
  ...
  public List<CartItem> Lines {get; set; }
}

public class CartItem
{
  public Product Product {get; set;}
  public int Quantity {get; set;}
  ...
}
```

In your view:

```
@model Cart
...
@using(Html.BeginForm())
{
  @{ int index = 0; }
  @foreach(var l in Model.Lines)
  {
    @Html.Hidden("cart.Lines.Index", index);
    @Html.Hidden("cart.Lines[" + index + "].Product.ProductID", l.Product.ProductID)
    @Html.TextBox("cart.Lines[" + index + "].Quantity")
    @{ index++; }
  }
  <input type="submit" value="Update Quantity" />
}
```

Your controller:

```
public ActionResult UpdateCart(Cart cart)
{
  // you should have new values on Quantity properties of the cart.Lines items.
}
```

Comment: This all looks correct but still does not work for me, all elements ID's match and it should bind to the cart object in session ? I am using a custom ModelBinder to automatically instantiate a new cart in session if it does not exist and hence provide this cart object to controllers\action methods. I am thinking this binder is to blame...

Answer (score 0):

Wouldn't it be easier to have an Object - say BasketItem that has the productId and the quantity as Properties? so you would have one array/list/ienumerable to pass on to update and to bind.

Your problem would be obsolete since the connection between quantity and productid is done via the object.

Comment: I tried the autobind to model object approach. Basically created a class\object (UpdateModel) with two public properties int ProductId {get; set:} and int partquantity {get; set:} then in the Action method parameter I specified a parameter: List<UpdateModel> Model. However it would not bind to this model and populate the list, irrespective of what I called the elements in the view. I had also tried creating a "public List<UpdateModel> {get; set:} property in another model object\class, this also did not work.

Comment: hm ... than you're right - that problem is probably the binder. have you debugged it and checked if the session variable behaves correctly?